# automatic link creation using php without breaking the html tags

Tags: php, javascript

i want to convert text links in my content page into active links using php. i tried every possible script out there, they all fine but the problem that they convert links in img src tag. they convert links everywhere and break the html code.

i find a good script that do what i want exactly but it is in javascript. it is called jquery-linkify.
you can find the script here
http://github.com/maranomynet/linkify/

the trick in the script that it convert text links without breaking the html code. i tried to convert the script into php but failed.

i cant use the script on my website because there is other scripts that has conflict with jquery.

anyone could rewrite this script for php? or at least guide me how?

thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason as to why you don't like to use the jQuery linkify?

Comment: i cant use jQuery linkify on my website because there is other scripts(mootools) that has conflict with jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse the text with an HTML parser, with something like `DOMDocument::loadHTML`. Note that poor HTML can be hard to parse, and depending on the parser, you might get slightly different output in the browser after running such a function.

PHP's `DOMDocument` isn't very flexible in that regard. You may have better luck by parsing with other tools. But if you are working with valid HTML (and you should try to, if it's within your control), none of that is a concern.

After parsing the text, you need to look at the text nodes for links and replace them. Using a regular expression is the simplest way.

Here's a sample script that does just that:

```
<?php
function linkify($text)
{
  $re = "@\b(https?://)?(([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+:)?[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().&=+$%-]+\@)?(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}|([0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'()-]+\.)*([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]{0,61})?[0-9a-zA-Z]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})(:[0-9]{1,4})?((/[0-9a-zA-Z_!~*'().;?:\@&=+$,%#-]+)*/?)@";
  preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

  $matches = $matches[0];

  $i = count($matches);
  while ($i--)
  {
    $url = $matches[$i][0];
    if (!preg_match('@^https?://@', $url))
      $url = 'http://'.$url;

    $text = substr_replace($text, '<a href="'.$url.'">'.$matches[$i][0].'</a>', $matches[$i][1], strlen($matches[$i][0]));

  }

  return $text;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<b>stackoverflow.com</b> <a href="stackoverflow.com">test</a>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//text()') as $text)
{
  $frag = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
  $frag->appendXML(linkify($text->nodeValue));
  $text->parentNode->replaceChild($frag, $text);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

I did not come up with that regular expression, and I cannot vouch for its accuracy. I also did not test the script, except for this above case. However, this should be more than enough to get you going.

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
 <b><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a></b> 
 <a href="stackoverflow.com">test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `saveHTML()` adds the surrounding tags. If that's a problem, you can strip them out with `substr()`.

Comment: i was thinking about this but in a different way. in jquery.linkify, he converts ">" and "<" into html entities. then uses the regular expression to search for links without qoutes, ">" and "<". i think this is the trick how not to touch the html tags.

Comment: i tried your code. it is very good and working but there is 2 problems.
1- the charachter encoding of the content is in arabic after running this through the script it gives unknown charachters like this:"Ø¨Ù„ÙŠÙ„ÙŠØ³Ù„ÙŠ". is there is anyway we can adjust the encoding?
2- the script converts the links like this(http://www. and www.) but dont convert the links like this one(http://yahoo.com).

Comment: this is the substr() code :


$demessago = $dom->saveHTML();

$rest = substr($demessago, 119, -14); 
 
    
$text_new = $rest;

Comment: @alhoseany, you can replace the regular expression with one that works better. I just copied it from a Google search. It should pretty much be a drop-in replacement. Regarding encoding, you could try using `utf8_decode()` or `utf8_encode()` on the `saveHTML` method might help. I don't know which direction the problem lies.

Comment: @alhoseany: this worked for me:  $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$html);

Answer (score 0):

Use a [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and only search for URLs within text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the trick is in tracking the single ' and double quotes '' in your PHP code and merging between them in a correct way so you put '' inside "" or vice versa.

For Example,

```
   <?PHP

   //old html tags
   echo "<h1>Header1</h1>";
   echo "<div>some text</div>";

   //your added links
   echo "<p><a href='link1.php'>Link1</a><br>";
   echo "<a href='link1.php'>Link1</a></p>";

   //old html tags
   echo "<h1>Another Header</h1>";
   echo "<div>some text</div>";

   ?>
```

I hope this helps you ..

Comment: i think you are right about the quotes. in jquery.linkify it uses this regular expression. '/(?:^|["'(\s]|&lt;)(www\..+?\..+?)(?:(?:[:?]|\.+)?(?:\s|$)|&gt;|[)"',])/g,'

Comment: and in this regex there is double and single qoutes. i dont know how to escape them inside the regex without breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'Any text ... link  http://example123.com  and image <img src="http://exaple.com/image.jpg" />';
$text = preg_replace('!([^\"])(http:\/\/(?:[\w\.]+))([^\"])!', '\\1<a href="\\2">\\2</a>\\3', $text);
```

Comment: your code is very good. simple and does not break html tags but it does not convert links like this:
-www.yahoo.com
-http://example.com/data